# Stack Exchange beta sites have some dust on them

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, design, beta-sites

I was browsing around the exchange and noticed a speck of crud on my screen.  Only, when I tried to wipe it off, it turned out to be part of the site.  Have a look at [some SE question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/how-can-i-play-dumb) between the "link" and "improve this question" links.

On Mac Safari 5.1.2 and Chrome 16.0.912.75 I see a speck:

[image: Out out!]

It goes away when the mouse is over "improve this question", but comes back on mouseout.  (For Safari you have to mouseout on the "link" side to get it back.)

Now I can't not see it.

## Please make it go away

<sup>I don't see this on FF 8+, but that's cold comfort if I'm not using it at the moment.</sup>

Comment: Such a tiny, minor thing. But I like how you put it. +1

Comment: It's not going away on mouseover in Firefox.

Comment: Why did you do this? Now I see it too...

Comment: "`<span class="lsep">|</span>`"   <== That little guy?  I wouldn't worry about that little guy.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what's supposed to be going on there, but the vertical pipe that's put between the links has `font-size: 1px` applied to it in the Sketchy style. Looks like the `visibility: hidden` that's used on other sites that don't display the separator is missing from `.lsep`.

Comment: @AndrewBarber and his up voters: tiny is not equal to minor.

Comment: I can see it in FF8.

Comment: In other sites the size is 110% and defined in same file (all.css) - guess beta sites have their own CSS files which are out of date or contain some bugs.

Comment: This probably won't be fixed...sketchy's days are numbered.

Comment: @Kris If I thought tiny was equal to minor, I would not have used both words.

Comment: @NickCraver That sounds...a bit sketchy. Should the graph paper background fear for its life?

Comment: @NickCraver - Care to elaborate? Will we be hearing about Sketchy's replacement any time soon?

Comment: It’s beta, what did you expect?

Comment: @jadarnel27 +1 for the Super Troopers quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)... sort of.

We're [rolling out a new fancy beta theme](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/) to replace Sketchy, so this is fixed in the sense that Sketchy's being removed.